# python: How to pass parameter into SQL query

Tags: python-3.x, pandasql

I have a function with a parameter. This parameter must be replaced in a SQL query and then execute it by `pandasql`. Here is my function:

```
def getPolypsOfPaitentBasedOnSize(self,size):


   smallPolypQuery = """ 
                       select *
                       from     polyp 
                       where polyp.`Size of Sessile in Words` ==  """ +size

   smallPolyps = ps.sqldf(smallPolypQuery)
```

When i run the code, i get the below error:

```
    raise PandaSQLException(ex)
pandasql.sqldf.PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: Small
[SQL:  
                       select *
                       from     polyp 
                               where polyp.`Size of Sessile in Words` ==  Small]
```

it seems that, i have to somehow make it like

```
 where polyp.`Size of Sessile in Words` == 'Small'
```

but, i don't know, how to do it!

***Update:***

I have tired the below solution and also there is no error but the query does not return anything

```
""" 
    select *
    from     polyp 
    where polyp.`Size of Sessile in Words` ==  " """ +size+ """ " """
```

I am sure (if the `size="Small"`)the statement like below will work for me:

```
where polyp.`Size of Sessile in Words` ==  "Small"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`format` can be used.

```
size = 'Small'

smallPolypQuery = """ 
select *
from   polyp 
where  polyp.`Size of Sessile in Words` ==  {0}""".format(size)

print(smallPolypQuery)
```

The resule is:

```py
select *
from   polyp 
where  polyp.`Size of Sessile in Words` ==  Small
```

If you need quote then put it to the smallPolypQuery such as:

```
smallPolypQuery = """ 
select *
from   polyp 
where  polyp.`Size of Sessile in Words` ==  "{0}" """.format(size)
```